# How to save images image model at the time of creating new posts in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a blog like application in rails. and I want my every post(Letters) to have multiple images, so I made two separate tables for letterss and images(one to many relationships). can someone please tell me how to save images with proper letter_id's at the time of creation of new posts.

P.S. I am very new to rails, please explain in an elaborate way. Really appreciate the help.

letters_controller.rb

```
class LettersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_letter, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
before_action :require_same_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    @letters = Letter.all
end

def new
    @letter = Letter.new
end

def create
    @letter = Letter.new(letter_params)
    @letter.user = current_user
    if @letter.save
        flash[:success] = 'Letter submitted successfully...'
        redirect_to letter_path(@letter)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
    if @letter.update(letter_params)
        flash[:success] = 'Letter updated successfully...'
        redirect_to letter_path(@letter)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def show
    # @letter_images = Image.find("letter_id = ?", params[:id])
end

def destroy
    @letter.destroy
    flash[:success] = 'Letter removed successfully...'
    redirect_to root_path
end 
private

def set_letter
    @letter = Letter.find(params[:id])
end

def letter_params
    params.require(:letter).permit(:title, :description, images_attributes: 
    [:picture])
end

def require_same_user
    if current_user != @letter.user and !current_user.admin?
        flash[:danger] = 'you can only edit your own letters'
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1 align="center">Create a Letter</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', obj: @letter %>

<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-12'>
        <%= form_for(@letter, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
                    <%= f.label :title %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Title of letter", autofocus: true %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
                    <%= f.label :description %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 10, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Body of letter" %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
                    <%= f.label :picture %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png, image/jpg', class: "form-control", placeholder: "Upload an Image" %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
            [ <%= link_to "Cancel request and return to letters listing", letters_path %> ]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

show.html.erb

```
<h2 align="center">Title: <%= @letter.title %></h2>
<div class="well col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
  <% if @letter.user %>
    <ul class="listing" style= "list-style:none;">
      <div class="row center">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
          <li>Created by:</li>          
          <li class="letter-title">
            <%= link_to @letter.user.name, user_path(@letter.user) %>
          </li>
          <li><small>
            <%= pluralize(@letter.user.letters.count, "letter") if @letter.user.letters %>
          </small></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  <% end %>

  <% if @letter.images %>
    <%= image_tag(@letter.images, size: "300x300") %>
  <% end %>

  <h4 class="center description"><strong>Description:</strong></h4>
  <hr>
  <%= simple_format(@letter.description) %>
  <div class="letter-actions">
    <% if logged_in? && (current_user == @letter.user || current_user.admin?) %>
      <%= link_to "Edit this letter", edit_letter_path(@letter), class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "Delete this letter", letter_path(@letter), method: :delete, 
                                        data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete the letter?"}, 
                                        class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to "View all letters", letters_path, class: "btn btn-xs btn-success" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share your posts_controller, images_controller, routes code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Any solution will depend on the code you have set up so far so can you share your code, at least the  images upload form and then maybe the controllers the others asked about.

Comment: Sorry for not sharing the code. I will update it now.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose your models look like this:

```
class Post
  has_many :images
end

class Image
  belongs_to :post
end
```

And also suppose your post model has a `title` attribute, and your image model has a `url` attribute you're saving the image path into. Here is a way to do it:

a) add a call to accept nested attributes:

```
class Post
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end
```

b) Change your controller to permit attributes on images as well:

```
class PostsController
   ... actions code ...

   def post_params
     params.require(:post).permit(:title, images_attributes: [:url])
  end
end
```

c) Lastly, it's time to change your form:

```
= form_for @post do |f|
  %h2 Post
  %p
    = f.label :title
    = f.text :title

  %h2 Images
  = f.fields_for :images do |fi|
    %p
      = fi.label :url
      = fi.text :url

  = f.submit
```

This will allow that, when you submit your form and it goes to `PostsController#create`, it creates the posts with the images in it.

I can't see your models but I did notice your form is submitting the actual file, so for that you need to send `multipart: true` in the form html parameters. Do some research on how to send multipart forms in Rails and you'll find it (but this is a bit unrelated to this question).

Then, make sure you have a good upload/image processing. [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) + [rmagick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick) gems seem to be the most popular

Comment: I tried what you said, but it didn't seem to work. Can you suggest something else by seeing the code??

Comment: Yes looking now.

Comment: @PulkitGoel I added a couple sentences to my answer, hopefully they will provide you a better way forward.

Comment: Yes sir, I am using carrierwave for handling uploads. And I made the form mutilpart. But it's still showing the same error. Am I displaying the image correctly in the show.html.erb file??